# Passing an exclude option to Rack::SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, rack

Following the guidance [here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/), updated for Rails 3.2.x, I expected to be able to configure Rack::SSL to use the SSL filters only if an `https://` prefix is included:

```
config.force_ssl = true
config.ssl_options = { :exclude => proc { |env| puts 'here? ' + env.to_s; env['HTTPS'] != 'on' } }
```

However, `https` works, where `http` fails with the following error:

```
[2012-10-29 15:37:03] ERROR OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_accept returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read client hello A: http request
    /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/openssl/ssl-internal.rb:164:in `accept'
```

The diagnostic code inserted into the lambda is not executed.  How can I configure Rack:SSL in Rails 3.2.x to respond to both HTTP and HTTPS?

Rails 3.2.8, WEBrick configured for SSL using a self-signed cert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to use the `exclude` option in the `options` hash has been removed as of May 2012 for some reason:  https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5515

The error I was seeing was a red herring.  The `exclude` was being ignored and the `http://` request was being redirected in [ActionDispatch::SSL](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/ssl.rb) to `https://`.  OpenSSL was then choking (I assume) because of the protocol mismatch.

The solution is to use the `rack-ssl` gem, as suggested [here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/#comment-43321).  This is essentially identical to ActionDispatch::SSL, except that the `exclude` option is still respected.

Comment: I followed the same approach, still can't use my app on http? Any idea what could be wrong ? I am using rails 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to `rack-ssl` is to use the [rack-ssl-enforcer](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer), configured as follows:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.middleware.use Rack::SslEnforcer, :except => ['/heatlh_check', %r{^/public/}]
```

Answer (score 0):

After days with wrestling with configs, etc I found this great gem:

https://github.com/lserman/aws-healthcheck

No need for any custom nginx setup (it works through rack). It returns `200` on /healthcheck which works like a charm. Just add it to your gems and you are done.